# Authentication with spring and web flux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a question concerning spring and web flux.
I have a spring project with spring security and MVC as dependencies.
This application accepts requests and check authentication using the session cookie.
For all the requests starting with "/api/" a failed authentication results in a 401 response, so that can be intercepted by the frontend as such.
For all the requests different from "/api/**" a failed authentication results in the server returning a login page so that the user can login.

This is the SecuritConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
     .formLogin()
     .and()
     .csrf()
     .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
     .and()
     .exceptionHandling()
     .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new
      HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED),
                     new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
     .and()
     .cors();
 }

}
```

Now, I am trying to achieve the same thing using web flux. With web flux the SecurityConfig is different, I can setup almost all the configs that I have in the old class but there is no equivalent for:

```
defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new
HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED),
                     new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
```

My new security config look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

 @Bean
 public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http)  {
     return http
             .authorizeExchange()
             .pathMatchers("/login/**")
             .permitAll()
             .anyExchange()
             .authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .and()
             .csrf()
             .disable()
             .exceptionHandling()
             .authenticationEntryPoint(new
HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
             .and()
             .build();
 }
```

}

But in this case I only get 401 for all the requests that fail authentication.
Does anybody know how to achieve the same behavior with web flux?
Thank you